# Битовые операции - есть данные в hex, необходимо взять только нужную часть из hex.

Tags: python, битовые-операции

Всем привет! Есть данные в hex: `0x000407d10001` необходимо взять только нужную часть из hex: это `01` и `07d1`.

Можно и так сделать:

```
c = '0x000407d10001'
c[12:]
c[6:-4]
```

Необходимо сделать это все в двоичной bin. Задача стоит чтобы максимально быстро выполнялась операция, я думаю если это операция будет в bin выполняться то скорость ее будет выше.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Это можно сделать с помощью масок. Предположим, нужно просмотреть значение 1 байта и 3+4 байтов (как в Вашей задаче). Делаем маски

```
n=0x000407d10001

m1=0xFF
m34=0xFFFF0000

print "Byte 1: %X" % (n & m1) 
print "Bytes 3-4: %X" % ((n & m34) >> 16)
```